# difference between creating IBOutlet of a UIView and creating a UIView using tag?

Tags: ios

I don't know which is efficient and why, I have a xib file which have some view, and I'm confuse that what should I do either create IBOutlet for each view, or create UIView at runtime whenever I needed that view.

Comment: If the XIB creates the view use an outlet

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has both used xib files and built UIs programmatically, I would recommend you use whatever you are comfortable with.  There is no one-size-fits-all-situations answer.

However, if you are working as part of a team, I would recommend that you use xibs and/or auto-layout storyboards, which are generally easier for someone (not as intimately familiar with the view as the creator) to make changes to, rather than sift through many (sometimes many many) lines of programmatic view creation/placement/sizing code.

Answer (score 0):

it your choice. IBOutlet will loose some bunch of code and YES Creating UIView excute at runtime and u can make multiple view.